# Is it possible to know the request of the Source to a web Application?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am working on a Java EE based Web Application , which consists of Jersey RestFul Webservices .
Is it possible to  know , from where the  request for a Jersey RestFul Webservice has come means if

1.The request is **from Web Service client tool**  (For ex : Google Chromes Rest Client , or any such tools like that  )

2  Or **the request is made  from the Logged in User** .

Inside my Service class  , i have kept this condition .

// This condition works fine for the Web Service Client Tools .

```
HttpSession httpsession = req.getSession(false);
if(httpsession==null)
{
throw new WebApplicationException(SC_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

This works fine for handling the Webservice client tools which simply throws Forbidden Exception as a response to the service call , but there might be also a condition where a logged in user , Might delete the Jsession Id Cookie from the Browser and then might make a call to one of the Service , any such type of request i want to redirect him to the Login page .

So basically i was asking , is it possible to know from where the request has been made ??

Answer (score 0):

One way to address REST security issues is with the open-source protocol OAuth. As described on the [OAuth website](http://oauth.net/), OAuth is "an open protocol to allow secure API authorization in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications." OAuth incorporates common principles employed by several proprietary frameworks, including Google AuthSub, AOL OpenAuth, Yahoo BBAuth, Upcoming API, Flickr API, and Amazon Web Services API.

The OAuth protocol enables a website or application (known as a service consumer) to access protected resources from a web service (known as a service provider) through an API. The API does not require users to disclose their service provider credentials to consumers.

Comment: Thanks Lars , but as is said the Unauthorized access to a service is already been solved , now the issue is to show the appropriate message depending upon request types .